# Dual Boot - Ubuntu disappeared

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot

I own a windows 10 pc which is dual booted with Ubuntu 16.x version. Recently an executable file has been dropped in my desktop by microsoft(I didn't download, or did something) with the name windows10 update agent. After verifying that it is actually from Microsoft I executed the file. It said new and important windows upgrade is available so I have upgraded. It displayed the upgrade successful message

[The message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idnCG.png)

Everything was fine until I restart my PC for logging into Ubuntu but it has straight away gone to Windows 10 user account login page.

What to do in this case? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If UEFI just change the boot order back to Ubuntu. If BIOS you may have a problem now requiring Grub reinstallation or, worse case scenario, reinstalling Ubuntu itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options to repair booting into Ubuntu. First, be sure Windows is shut down without hiberfil.sys or [Fast Startup](https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/) or the HDD will not be accessible in write mode.

1. Download a version of Ubuntu and [create installation media](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0). Boot from the USB drive (or DVD) to "try Ubuntu", then [install boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and try it.
2. If boot-repair did not resolve the issue, then you may need [to manually change the UEFI boot order](https://www.lifewire.com/change-the-efi-boot-order-efibootmgr-4028027).
3. If all else fails, using Ubuntu boot media, *back up the UEFI boot loaders* and then replace the UEFI boot file in `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/bootmgfw.efi` with that in a previously-working Ubuntu folder, renamed to *bootmgfw.efi*. *N.B.* this is deceptive, if someone needs to troubleshoot bootup, but I admit to doing this to resolve an issue where even *uninstalling Windows* and reinstalling Ubuntu did not work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem - dual boot Windows 10/Lubuntu computer which would no longer show the GRUB dual boot menu after the Spring 2018 Windows 10 upgrade. 
My Dell system has an F12 (Boot Order) key that saved me a lot of potential work: I kept pressing F12 during startup, and the computer went into its own boot menu with separate entries for Windows and Lubuntu.
Once I booted into Lubuntu, I opened a Terminal and entered "sudo grub-install /dev/sda"   (both operating systems are on sda on my computer). Grub dual boot menu was reinstalled and dual boot is working fine again.  Total time about 3 minutes. 
Hope your system has the same options available.

Answer (score 0):

Steps that worked for me:

1. Boot from ubuntu installation media (choose: Try ubuntu)
2. Identify your disk e.g. /dev/sda
3. Identify these two partitions: using gparted

   1. EFI partition e.g. /dev/sda1
   2. Ubuntu root partition e.g. /dev/sda5
4. Run in terminal (after replacing proper disk & partition names):

```bash
sudo mount /dev/sda{ROOT} /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda{EFI} /mnt

for i in /dev /run /proc /sys /dev/pts; do
    sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i
done

sudo chroot /mnt
mount -t efivarfs none /sys/firmware/efi/efivars    # for ubuntu 22
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub

sudo umount /dev/sda{ROOT}
sudo umount /dev/sda{EFI}
exit # and reboot
```

Method adapted from: https://askubuntu.com/a/831241/1124495